# What is the type parameter V in parboiled used for

Tags: java, parboiled

Some classes in the parboiled framework have a generic type parameter. E.g. the class [`BaseParser`](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled/blob/master/parboiled-java/src/main/java/org/parboiled/BaseParser.java). In it's documentation it says:

```
Type Parameters:
    V - the type of the parser values
```

which I really not find a sufficient documentation. The documentation in the other classes is similiar or missing. Even in the wiki I didn't find information on that. They are just using `Object`.

Can anyone explain to me what this parameter is used for and what are valid types to hand over?

Comment: Could the downvoter please give a reason so I can improve (future) questions?

Answer (score -1):

The Type of the parsed values, like Integer for "999". See the calc example:
 [CalculatorParser0.java](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled/blob/master/examples-java/src/main/java/org/parboiled/examples/calculators/CalculatorParser0.java)

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't really help me much. It doesn't really say more than the documentation and the example doesn't show how the type parameter influences the behaviour. Could you elaborate?

Comment: CalculatorParser0 doesn't demonstrate this, see [CalculatorParser1](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled/blob/master/examples-java/src/main/java/org/parboiled/examples/calculators/CalculatorParser1.java) instead.